# Can't import HTML or XML in google sheet

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, web-scraping, import, google-sheets-formula

i'm new to using this function, can anyone help me getting this data from this website? (https://www.myfxbook.com/community/outlook/EURUSD)
I need to import the first table, in particular i need the Long and Short %

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=IMPORTHTML(A1, "table", 2)
```

[image]

then you can do simple extract:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTHTML(A1, "table", 2), "select Col2,Col3 offset 2", 0)
```

[image]

Comment: I have try to use the same method on another web site but didn't work, maybe i miss something idk. (https://tradingeconomics.com/united-states/indicators) @player0 can you help for the last time?

Comment: @Tone there is no universal solution. every URL requires specific touch